# How does kibana interact with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

exactly how does kibana interact with elasticsearch(ES). All I know that it has to consume some REST API's to retrieve data, is it through **ES's angular client** or **ES's node client**?

And if any, can you help me locate this files inside kibana structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the client, it uses [elasticsearch-js](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js) to make requests to a proxy served by Kibana (/elasticsearch). The proxy has [whitelisted methods and endpoints](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/src/core_plugins/elasticsearch/index.js#L119) and is currently only used for search. Object persistence for Kibana is done through he [SavedObjectClient](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/pull/11632) and is a REST API served by Kibana.